# Refresh Parent Page after window.open javascript while child window contains window.print onload of it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to open a link in new tab and immediately refresh my page in JavaScript. But when I open a new tab using `window.open()`, it does't reload my page. it waits for new tab to be closed then refresh my page.
Although it works in IE. But Chrome is waiting to child window to be closed.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/MailMan/Print'
    , dataType: "json"
    , type: "POST"
    , success: function (result) {
        if (result.success == true) {
            window.open(
                '/MailMan/Index/Building/1/Shift/1'
                , '_blank'
            );

            window.location.reload();
        }
    }

});
```

The child page contains `window.print()` command in `onload()`of it. and when I close print dialog , main page refreshes successfully. This is my child page :

```
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<script>
    window.onload = function () {
        window.print();
    }
</script>

</head>
<body>
</body>
```

Comment: really it doesn't reload your current page?

Comment: Does it wait to _start_ the request; or does it start the request immediately, but then it takes the server a while to respond? Use your browser’s dev tools to verify.

Comment: check your console maybe you have an error

Comment: If it's waiting for the window.open to complete, then just put each line (open / reload) in separate setTimeouts with slightly increasing times (eg 50, 150).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change my child window as below and it works for me. although it bring print dialog 1 sec later but it's not a big deal for me.

```
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<script>
    window.onload = function () {
        window.setTimeout(window.print(),1000
        );
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
</body>
```